# SVG group Mouseover/Mouseout event

Tags: events, svg

In my svg file I have a rectangle that is initially a small size. Now when I mouse over that rectangle it increases the size of the rectangle and  displays a previously hidden text which is actually a link. Both of these elements are in a group.

Now I would like the behaviour that when the mouse leaves the overall group area, that only then the rectangle resizes to the initial small size and the link disappears again.

However my problem is that if moving the cursor over the link, a mouseout event will be triggered for the rectangle although the cursor is still theoretically over the group. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621919/svg-onmouseover-for-group-with-overlapping-elements-occurs-twice

Answer (score 0):

Nice functionality.

We have had the same problem with text over Raphael objects.
Here we avoided the problem by having an invisible front layer, a middle text layer and a coloured backlayer.
If you would like to look at the result it might inspire you.
Raphael sits well in the SVG world if you think you can venture towards it..

http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/additionalhelp.php?v=2&q=button